# Python inheriting base class variable

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

If I inherit a class variable from a base class, and then want to use that variable as a default parameter in a method in my child class, how do I access it?

```
def get_records_by_domain(self, domain, search_period_days=self._X):
```

where _X is a variable in a parent class that is instantiated in the **init** of the child class?

When I try to test this function, I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: go ahead and edit your question and include the two classes.

Comment: Function defaults are evaluated *when the function is created*, not when called; there is no instance available at that time. Use a sentinel (like `None`) for the default and test for that in your function body: `if search_period_days is None: search_period_days = self._X`.